# use nvc++ to run C++ program with OpenACC ,error shows :libgomp: TODO

Tags: c++, openacc

I used nvc++ to run the C++ program with openacc and the error displayed 'libgomp: TODO'.
Here is the test code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include<openacc.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(){

  cv::Mat srcImg=cv::imread("/home/testSpace/images/blue-mountains.jpg");
  if(!srcImg.data){

   cout<<"The file is not loaded or does not exist"<<endl;
   return -1;

  }


    cout<<"Matrix"<<srcImg.rows<<" "<<srcImg.cols<<endl;
    Mat duplicate(srcImg.rows,srcImg.cols, CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(255) ); 



    #pragma acc enter data copyin(srcImg[:srcImg.rows][:srcImg.cols])

    #pragma acc enter data copyin(duplicate[:duplicate.rows][:duplicate.cols])

    #pragma acc parallel

{

     #pragma acc loop

     for(int i=0;i<srcImg.rows;i++){

     #pragma acc loop

     for(int j=0;j<srcImg.cols;j++){

       duplicate.at<uchar>(i,j)=srcImg.at<uchar>(i,j);

    }

   }


   #pragma acc data copyout(duplicate[:duplicate.rows][:duplicate.cols])

   #pragma acc data copyout(srcImg[:srcImg.rows][:srcImg.cols])


 }

   cout<<"duplicate"<<": "<<(int)duplicate.at<uchar>(23,45)<<endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Then I got error by using nvc++ to compile the code file.

main:

```
    2216, Loop unrolled 4 times (completely unrolled)

 36, Generating enter data copyin(duplicate,srcImg)

     Generating NVIDIA GPU code

     38, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */

     40, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */

 36, Generating implicit copyin(duplicate.step.p[:1],srcImg.step.p[:1],srcImg,duplicate)[if not already present]

 40, Loop is parallelizable

     Loop not vectorized/parallelized: not countable
```

cv::Matx<double, (int)4, (int)1>::Matx():

The final result is :Matrix810 1440

libgomp: TODO

Can anyone please provide any hint? Moreover, I don't know why I got the error

> Generating implicit
> copyin(duplicate.step.p[:1],srcImg.step.p[:1],srcImg,duplicate)[if not
> already present]

I used the same way to allocate memory for srcImg in GPU.

The content of run scripts:

```
nvc++ -g -O3 -acc -gpu=cc60,cc70 -Minfo ``pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`` -nomp -o nvcpp.out  test.cpp
```

Please check lib_information [here](https://github.com/Lancelof2019/record_txt/blob/main/lib_information.txt)

Comment: I've seen this once when the loader was using the GNU OpenACC runtime library instead of the NVHPC OpenACC runtime.  Can you run 'ldd nvcpp.out" and see which libraries are being used?  Might also be a problem with pgk-config linking in the wrong OpenACC runtime.

Comment: Hello Mat, thanks for your messsage. I 've checked the lib information by using ldd nvpp.out.The information shows the related lib files are invoked from path  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. Please see more detail from attachment.

Comment: Please format & indent your code and question properly if you expect others to read them

Comment: May I know how I coud link the right openacc runtime?

Comment: I updated the run scripts in one test by removing invoking opencv,  error information of libgomp: TODO disappeared.